# How to prove that $\gamma \le 2$ for *causal* relativistic polytrope fluids?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, fluid-dynamics, ideal-gas, adiabatic

The definition of the adiabatic index of a *relativistic polytrope* fluid is this:
$$\tag{1}
\gamma = \frac{\rho + p}{p} \, \frac{dp}{d\rho},
$$
where $\rho$ is the *energy density* (not the *mass* density).  The sound velocity in the fluid is restricted by the principle of causality, so (I'm using units such that $c \equiv 1$):
$$\tag{2}
v_s^2 \equiv \frac{dp}{d\rho} \le 1 \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad \gamma \le \frac{\rho + p}{p}.
$$
For a constant $\gamma$, one solution to (1) is *non-linear*:
$$\tag{3}
\rho = \frac{p}{\gamma - 1} + (p / \kappa)^{1/\gamma},
$$
where $\kappa$ is a positive integration constant.  Then, a *linear* EoS (equation of state) is *another* solution for the same value of $\gamma$:
$$\tag{4}
\rho = \frac{1}{\gamma - 1} \, p.
$$
Clearly, *this* linear function has $v_s > 1$ for $\gamma > 2$.

In the special case of $\gamma = 2$, (3) can be inverted:
$$\tag{5}
p(\rho) = \frac{1}{4 \kappa} \bigl( \sqrt{1 + 4 \kappa \rho} - 1 \Bigr)^2.
$$
This *non-linear* EoS gives $p(\rho) \approx \kappa \rho^2$ when $4 \kappa \rho \ll 1$, and gives $p(\rho) \approx \rho$ when $4 \kappa \rho \gg 1$.  The speed of sound *is always lower than 1* (except in the limiting case $\rho \rightarrow \infty$):
$$\tag{6}
v_s^2 = \frac{dp}{d\rho} = 1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + 4 \kappa \rho}}.
$$
This could also be the case for $\gamma > 2$, when the EoS is *non-linear*, so from (1)-(3), how can we prove that $v_s \le 1 \; \Rightarrow \; \gamma \le 2$ even for a *non-linear* EoS?

Comment: The stiffest causal EoS is $p=\rho$ which yields the limiting case of $\gamma=2$.

Comment: @N0va, how do you derive this from the polytope expression (3)?  It implies $\kappa \rightarrow \infty$

Answer (score 2):

I am not really sure if I understood the question correctly to be honest but I will give an answer a try: the polytropes discussed here can be expressed in terms of number density $n$ as
$$
\begin{align}
p(n)&=k n^\gamma,\\
\rho(n)&=m n+\frac{k n^\gamma}{\gamma-1},
\end{align}
$$
which we may use to get the following closed expression for the speed of sound squared
$$
v_s^2=\frac{(\gamma -1) \gamma  k n^{\gamma }}{\gamma  k n^{\gamma }+(\gamma -1) m n}.
$$
This can be analyzed for different values of $\gamma$ and for $\gamma>1$ we may note that for large $n$ the denominator in the expression for $v_s^2$ is dominated by the term $n^\gamma$ for large $n$ and thus we find $v_s^2=\gamma-1$ for large $n$ and $\gamma>1$. Which yields $\gamma=2$ as the limit for a causal polytrope.

Comment: The conclusion depends on the absence of a limit to the number density $n$.  For example, we could use $\gamma = 3$ into your last equation, and find $n_{max}$ from the constraint $v_s^2 \le 1$.  It gives $$n \le n_{max} = \sqrt{\frac{2 m}{3 \kappa}}.$$This allows causal polytropes with $\gamma > 2$, at the condition $n < n_{max}$.  I'm not sure what to think of this.  Why should $n$ be without any *finite* upper limit?

Comment: In general, for $\gamma > 2$, we get $$v_s^2 \le 1 \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad n_{max}^{\gamma - 1} = \frac{m}{\gamma k} \Bigl( \frac{\gamma - 1}{\gamma - 2} \Bigr).$$

Comment: Getting into semantics a 'polytrope' with $\gamma>2$ would technically be a piecewise polytrope and a rather peculiar one at that: looking at Eq. (3) in the question one might notice that $\rho<p$ for small $p$ and $\gamma>2$ thus violating this "dominant energy condition". There might a gerneal connection here; a-causal EoS at high $n$ $\leftrightarrow$ violation of "dominant energy condition" at low $n$?

Comment: I don't understand your comment.  Violating the dominant energy condition means $p > \rho$, which implies the following inequalities for $\gamma > 2$:$$n^{\gamma - 1} > \frac{m}{k} \Bigl(  \frac{\gamma - 1}{\gamma -2} \Bigr) > \frac{m}{\gamma k} \Bigl( \frac{\gamma - 1}{\gamma - 2}  \Bigr) \equiv n_{max}^{\gamma - 1}.$$Thus, there's no violation of causality and no violation of the energy condition when $n < n_{max}$.  But I'm still perplexed by an upper limiting value of the particles density ($n_{max}$).

Comment: The upper limiting value of the particles density implies a maximal pressure (for $\gamma > 2$):$$p_{max} = k n_{max}^{\gamma} = k \Bigl[\frac{m}{\gamma k} \Bigl( \frac{\gamma - 1}{\gamma - 2} \Bigr) \Bigr]^{\frac{\gamma}{\gamma - 1}}.$$ Notice that $n_{max} \rightarrow \infty$ for $\gamma = 2$.  Once a star reaches the maximal pressure at the center, it would be violating the causality condition first (before the energy condition), and would probably collapse or abruptly explode.

Comment: N0va, I modified my *Mathematica* code to allow $\gamma > 2$ (as for the newtonian theory), with the physical constraint of causality $v_s \le 1$ which imposes a limit on the central pressure and on the maximal density.  The Mass-Radius graphical output is extremely interesting!  I get the spiral structure to smoothly fade away as I rise $\gamma$ above 2, while still satisfying the causality condition (and the *dominant* energy condition).  Using $\gamma \approx 3$ and up, I think this is interesting for neutron stars.